# Android Studio: Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android, android-studio, daemon

I'm facing the below error when I'm trying to import a gradle project in Android Studio.

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
```

and this is the output I see:

```
18:25:42.484 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252]
18:25:43.254 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.server.DaemonServices - Creating daemon context with opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252]
18:25:43.306 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer] Finished configuring with level: DEBUG, configurers: [org.gradle.logging.internal.OutputEventRenderer@47078ad, org.gradle.logging.internal.logback.LogbackLoggingConfigurer@7402a821, org.gradle.logging.internal.JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer@5a6c4a07]
18:25:43.356 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] start() called on daemon - DefaultDaemonContext[uid=e58252c1-7a49-4be4-a6cd-1bd3d6d0880d,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Sowmya\.gradle\daemon,pid=15432,idleTimeout=60000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252]
18:25:43.362 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] updating lastActivityAt to 1386593743362
18:25:43.702 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface lo
18:25:43.705 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? true
18:25:43.706 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
18:25:43.707 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
18:25:43.708 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface net0
18:25:43.711 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
DefaultDaemonContext[uid=e58252c1-7a49-4be4-a6cd-1bd3d6d0880d,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Sowmya\.gradle\daemon,pid=15432,idleTimeout=60000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252]
18:25:43.951 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
18:25:43.954 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
18:25:43.957 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
18:25:43.962 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
18:25:43.963 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
18:25:43.966 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
18:25:43.976 [ERROR] [system.err] 
18:25:43.977 [ERROR] [system.err] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
18:25:43.977 [ERROR] [system.err] 
18:25:43.978 [ERROR] [system.err] * What went wrong:
18:25:43.979 [ERROR] [system.err] Could not write cache value to 'C:\Users\Sowmya\.gradle\daemon\1.8\registry.bin'.
18:25:43.979 [ERROR] [system.err] 
18:25:43.980 [ERROR] [system.err] * Try:
18:25:43.981 [ERROR] [system.err] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
18:25:44.009 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain] Daemon[pid = 15432] process has finished.
18:25:44.010 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Removing daemon address: [9ae053cd-4dc2-4cb8-8f60-bb3c5983eb67 port:55117, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
18:25:44.011 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
18:25:44.012 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
18:25:44.013 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
18:25:44.014 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
18:25:44.015 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
18:25:44.016 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
18:25:44.021 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] VM shutdown hook was unable to remove the daemon address from the registry. It will be cleaned up later.
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not write cache value to 'C:\Users\Sowmya\.gradle\daemon\1.8\registry.bin'.
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.serialize(SimpleStateCache.java:74)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.access$100(SimpleStateCache.java:28)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache$2.run(SimpleStateCache.java:50)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:198)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:187)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.writeFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:58)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.set(SimpleStateCache.java:48)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.set(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:38)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.update(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.remove(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon$1.run(Daemon.java:100)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Sowmya\.gradle\daemon\1.8\registry.bin (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.serialize(SimpleStateCache.java:67)
    ... 10 more`
```

I've turned off my anti-virus which was mentioned in a solution in SO. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: From the answers it seems like a memory issue.  (deleting gradle didn't work for me)  I did the turn off and turn on computer and it worked.  If usually you don't get the error, it might help

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Try deleting your **.gradle** from `C:\Users\<username>` directory and try again.

Comment: I deleted the daemon file in C:\Uers\Sowmya.gradle directory and it worked. :) Thank you.

Comment: This also works if you get an error like "Could not read cache value from /Users/bj012293/.gradle/daemon/1.11/registry.bin"

Comment: unable to locate Somwya.gradle file :(

Comment: Oh its  C:\Uers\Sowmya\.gradle

Comment: I had an error: "Could not read cache value from /Users/username/.gradle/daemon/1.11/registry.bin" so I deleted the .gradle folder and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: @ScottBarta: would be honored if you take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30473371/3287204) ... :)

Comment: What if I need gradle.properties file, and need daemon running?

Comment: if i delete the .gradle folder it worked for that time but for the next time if i run android studio again it shows that error again.

Comment: I had the same problem as @umerk44 ! I had to delete .gradle everytime now, is someone fix that?

Answer (score 23):

1.If You just open too much applications in Windows and make the Gradle have no enough memory in Ram to start the daemon process.So when you come across with this situation,you can just close some applications such as iTunes and so on. Then restart your android studio.

2.File Menu - > Invalidate Caches/ Restart->Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: I just closed some applications, didnt have to restart the IDE. Upvote thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I also had same kind of issue. But managed to solve by Invalidate Cash.

From File Menu - > Invalidate Caches/ Restart..

It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

In Eclipse, go to windows -> preferences -> gradle->arguments. 
Find JVM Arguments  choose  from radio button "USE :" and write arguments -Xms128m -Xmx512m
Then click button  Apply

Answer (score 5):

Check your project folder. You may have there a file called gradle.properties and in there, check to see if you don't have this line:

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

In my case, I just deleted the file, but check the contents to see if you don't actually want to keep some of the settings.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...  I have tried and work fine for me

This issue is related to low memory...

Close your browsers, visual Studio and other services..

after that run following command

```
ionic build android
```

it will run successfully..

```
//Solutions is
create "gradle.properties" file in android folder and add following line into file
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

<your project>\platforms\android\gradle.properties
```

You can open browser and others..

```
ionic build android
```

Now it will work fine.

Comment: This solution works with Visual Studio Code and the Cordova Tools plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes You just open too much applications in Windows and make the gradle have no enough memory to start the daemon process.So when you come across with this situation,you can just close some applications such as Chrome and so on. Then restart your android studio.

Answer (score 1):

For me, in our work environment, we have Windows 7 64-bit with the machines locked down running McAfee with Host Intrusion turned on.

I turned off Host Intrusion and gradle would finally work, so definitely, it appears to be issues with certain Virus scanners.

UPDATE: Well I spoke too soon. Yes, I know longer get the "Unable to start the daemon process" message, but now I get the following:

Error:Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-revision.[ext]'.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same issue, and none of the other answers here helped my particular case.

It turned out to be because my Android Studio project was defaulting to use JDK 8.

Changing this, in the project settings, to point at a JDK 7 installation fixed this for me.

Comment: thank you, I had set my java home to an older version of java to build some ant projects, forgot to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in intellij idea and solved by doing this,

try to set "VM options" to -Xmx512m at Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Gradle VM options

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve problem in android studio

1. Click on **file** and select a **other setting** from dropdown menu and then select **default setting**.
2. Select **build,Execution,Deployment option**.
3. Select **Compiler**
4. Here add a following line in **Additional build process VM option**

   ```
   -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=524m as shown in below figure.
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem by just deleting **.gradle** folder within my application project..

Delete folder **.gradle** from your project no need to delete main .gradle folder which is located at `C:\Users\<username>`

Answer (score 0):

Some ways of troubleshooting the Gradle daemon:

- If you have a problem with your build, try temporarily disabling the daemon (you can pass the command line switch `--no-daemon`).
- Occasionally, you may want to stop the daemons either via the --stop command line option or in a more forceful way.
- There is a daemon log file, which by default is located in the Gradle user home directory.
- You may want to start the daemon in --foreground mode to observe how the build is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will fix the problem for everyone , But uninstalling java, java SDK and installing the latest version (Version 8) fixed the issue for me ..

Comment: // , How do you know that's what fixed it?

Comment: I was trying everything listed here(And something listed in youtube videos too...) When I checked the Java version I have, I happen see two versions listed, And I doesn't know which one is android studio is directed to..  So just uninstalled both and tried installing version 8 alone. After that when I run the same code in studio it started working..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's wrong JAVA_HOME make this error.
when i get error i try all the way,but it don't work for me.
i try delete c:.gradle and Compiler Android studio but it's still don't work.
i Re-install the system it work, when update system i get the error again.
I try Compiler JAVA_HOME user environment and system environment:
[image]

when i use cmd input java:

[image]

when cmd.exe show the masage it mean it's work, try to runing Android Studio, it will fix the error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mac try this :

```
cd Users/<Your name>
```

Make sure that you are on the right path by looking for .gradle with

```
ls -la
```

then run that to delete .gradle

```
rm -rf .gradle
```

This will remove everything. Then launch your commande again and it will work !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a good solution; but I changed

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

in gradle.properties
with this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

And i passed that error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything in this thread. From removing .gradle folders to invalidating caches and increasing the org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2512m argument. Nothing helped. I then removed the whole "org.gradle.jvmargs" line (it contained on the -Xmx... argument), restarted Android Studio and it worked.

Not sure why this helped, maybe if it the argument is gone, It automatically uses all the available RAM. I get this problem on Windows only, on Linux version of Android Studio it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

just go to your .gradle folder in pc c:/users/yourUsername/.gradle and delete cached folder

Answer (score -1):

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
```

This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized JVM option is used.

Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Comment: Welcome to SO (Stack Overflow)! Please mend the spelling (use of blanks) in your post. If `Error: Unable to start the daemon process.` is meant to be a quote, make it stand out as such, using a block quote or backticks (see editing help). I find a post ending in a colon irritating.

Answer (score -2):

You need to install all necessary packages with Android SDK Manager:

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools
- SDK Platform
- ARM\Intel System Image
- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library