# while importing project in Android Studio throws 'Project refresh failed' error

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I am a new bee for Android Studio,
while i import any android gradle(e.g. github.com/k9mail/k-9) project in studio,
it shows a bulk of errors:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
```

This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error: Could not find or load main class Xmx512m

i also changed the `"Gradle VM option"` under `File>>Setting >>Gradle  to "Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"`

but not worked for me.

Also in the "VM option" under `File >> Setting >> Compiler(Gradle-based Android Projects)` i changed the VM option to `Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`, but not worked for me,

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what project are you importing? Is it an android project with gradle?

Comment: yup! 
this project i am importing:
https://github.com/k9mail/k-9

Comment: Can you try deleting your gradle home directory(.gradle) directory and try to import again?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471311/android-studio-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process

Comment: i tried deleting the .gradle, and also i fixed the "Error:Unable to start the daemon process" error, now it shows, Error:(23, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'