# Android Studio 1.2.2 error on start: Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting this error on start of Android Studio

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
```

I now there are same questions about this error on StackOverflow, which I checked. But none of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479940/1281063) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28654846/1281063) solve my problem.

There is my log:

```
2015-06-25 20:40:19,400 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-06-25 20:40:19,555 [    155]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-141.1980579, 03 Jun 2015 00:00) 
2015-06-25 20:40:19,555 [    155]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 7 (6.1, x86) 
2015-06-25 20:40:19,555 [    155]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_45-b15 (Oracle Corporation) 
2015-06-25 20:40:19,555 [    155]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.45-b02 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM) 
2015-06-25 20:40:19,561 [    161]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.2 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Djb.vmOptions=D:\Programs\Androind Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:D:\Programs\Androind Studio\lib\boot.jar -Didea.jre.check=false 
2015-06-25 20:40:20,161 [    761]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (32-bit) in 600 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:20,166 [    766]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2015-06-25 20:40:20,168 [    768]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2015-06-25 20:40:23,863 [   4463]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 25 plugins initialized in 1604 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:23,874 [   4474]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.2.2), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage, EditorConfig (1.0), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Cloud Testing (1.0), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (0.1), JavaFX (1.0), Maven Integration, Properties Support, Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2015-06-25 20:40:25,211 [   5811]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=502530048 
2015-06-25 20:40:25,294 [   5894]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: D:\Programs\Androind Studio\bin\fsnotifier.exe 
2015-06-25 20:40:25,325 [   5925]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2015-06-25 20:40:26,671 [   7271]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2015-06-25 20:40:28,019 [   8619]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2015-06-25 20:40:28,836 [   9436]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-06-25 20:40:28,973 [   9573]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 20 project components initialized in 926 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:28,974 [   9574]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:30,428 [  11028]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 83 application components initialized in 6508 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:30,505 [  11105]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 13109 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:34,435 [  15035]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-06-25 20:40:34,920 [  15520]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 136 project components initialized in 2269 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:35,056 [  15656]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 1 module(s) loaded in 135 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:40,596 [  21196]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 4191 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:44,018 [  24618]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Gradle distribution at 'D:\Programs\Androind Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1' 
2015-06-25 20:40:44,232 [  24832]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - D:\AndroidProjects\Sunshine-Version-2\.idea\misc.xml case-sensitivity: false 
2015-06-25 20:40:44,428 [  25028]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45 
2015-06-25 20:40:44,447 [  25047]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45 
2015-06-25 20:40:44,703 [  25303]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'D:\Programs\Androind Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2015-06-25 20:40:45,701 [  26301]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2015-06-25 20:40:45,973 [  26573]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 2 
2015-06-25 20:40:49,218 [  29818]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Ippo\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo0.gradle, --init-script, C:\Users\Ippo\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit0.gradle] 
2015-06-25 20:40:50,738 [  31338]   INFO - nject.config.XPathSupportProxy - XPath Support is not available 
2015-06-25 20:40:53,208 [  33808]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 20636 ms 
2015-06-25 20:40:55,650 [  36250]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'D:\Programs\Androind Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:350)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:322)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:215)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:112)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:105)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:115)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:107)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:101)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:174)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:105)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-06-25 20:40:55,662 [  36262]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at 'D:/AndroidProjects/Sunshine-Version-2' 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'D:\Programs\Androind Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:350)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:322)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:215)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:112)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:105)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:115)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:107)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:101)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:174)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:105)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-06-25 20:40:55,689 [  36289]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:437)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:164)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:329)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:356)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:322)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:215)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)

2015-06-25 20:40:55,693 [  36293]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2015-06-25 20:40:55,693 [  36293]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------


Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Comment: What happens if you execute `/.gradlew build` in your project's root directory?

Comment: @nhaarman you mean on CMD? how exactly can I execute this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with how much memory is available for AS to create a VM environment for your app to populate. The thing is that ever since the update to 2.2 I've had the same problem every time I try to create a new project in AS.

How I solve it is by going into Project (on the left hand side) > Gradle Scripts > gradle.properties. When it opens the file go to the line under "(Line 10)# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process. (Line 11)# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings." You're looking for the line that starts with "org.gradle.jvmargs". This should be line 12. Change line 12 to this

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

After changing this line you can either sync the gradle with the project by clicking Try again on the notification telling you the gradle sync failed (it'll be at the top of the file you opened). Or you can simply close and restart the AS and it should sync.

Essentially what this is saying is for AS to allocate more memory to the app initialization. I know it's not a permanent fix but it should get you through actually starting your app.

Alternatively, you could also delete your .gradle folder (it should be found in C:\Users(your username). Deleting it will force Android to create a new one and will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug which is reported here,

[Issue 93641:   Detect 32bit gradle configured with too much ram and offer fix.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93641)

Check the responses posted in the bug tracker which might solve your problem.

Here's the first response,

> It looks like Android Studio can't launch the Gradle daemon JVM, and I
>   suspect it's because you're on a 32-bit machine running out of memory.
>
> What does Task Manager report for used/free memory when the error
>   happens?
>
> When 64-bit is not an option, I would try to tweak the -Xmx settings
>   such that both Android Studio and the Gradle daemon JVMs can "fit" in:
>   - for the Gradle daemon, try -Xmx512m in Default Settings > Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects) > VM options or in the project's
>   gradle.properties file.
>   - for Android Studio, I would try lowering Xmx to 750m (see also http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration).

Comment: I try your approach but nothing happen..
In mine error doesn't referred that occurred during initialization of VM..