# Gradle project sync failed basic functionality

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

My version AS 1.5
Today, i opened my  project and got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0F5e.png) issues.

Restart invalid cache does not help...Uptade sdk tools does not help...

my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471311/android-studio-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix it is to close Android Studio (to avoid removing problems) and delete this directory:

```
 C:\Users\<username>\.gradle
```

Then open your AS 1.5 and try to rebuild your project.

NOTE: `.gradle` may be a hidden folder. If true, follow these steps:

> To enable the viewing of hidden and protected system files in Windows
>    7 please follow these steps:
>
> 1. Close all programs so that you are at your desktop.
> 2. Click on the Start button.
> 3. This is the small round button () in the lower left corner of your screen that has a Windows flag on it.
> 4. Click on the Control Panel menu option.
> 5. Click on the Appearance and Personalization link.
> 6. Now click on the Show hidden files and folders option.
>      Under the Hidden files and folders section select the radio button labeled Show hidden files, folders, and drives.
> 7. Remove the checkmark from the checkbox labeled Hide extensions for known file types.
> 8. Remove the checkmark from the checkbox labeled Hide protected operating system files (Recommended).
> 9. Press the Apply button and then the OK button. You will now be at  your desktop and Windows 7 will be configured to show all hidden 
>      files.
>
> From: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/show-hidden-files-in-windows-7/

Comment: This is gradle compile folder. If i delet it, how will gradle work?

Comment: It would recreate the folder on next run of Android Studio

Comment: It works great, thanks a lot

Comment: I it works, don't forget to mark as answer, it would help other peeople with the same problem