# Android Studio 2.3.1 | Gradle "AppName" project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

For 2 days I can't start coding my first android app, because of an issue with Android Studio 2.3.1.
There is many discussions about that out there, but non of them helped me so far.

I'm not able to use Run button for my app or even to edit the `main_activity.xml` file in the program window. Also the following error occurs when Android Studio starts running.

Screen shot of the error:

[image: Screen shot of the error]

I'm workin' on Windows 7, 64bit, 8gb RAM, Java 1.8.0.121. Installed Android Studio 2.3.1 using android-studio-bundle-162.3871768-windows.exe file with **no** custom settings.

To solve the problem I've tried:

- reinstall Android Studio
- remove `.gradle` catalog
- use `File>>Invalidate Crashes/Restart`

nothing helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471311/android-studio-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

In my particular case the problem was caused by uncomplete Android Studio installation.

The reason of such an installation was Comodo **AntiVirus**

I noticed that there was some `.bat` files blocked during the installation. Comodo doesn't inform about it, but you can check it on blocked features list.

So I removed completely Android Studio, turned off all blocking functions in Comodo and quited it. Then installed AS once again.
Now it works fine. Ad least so far... Luckilly there's no Gradle error, so I hope there won't occur further problems.

Hope that this tip's gonna be helpful to somebody.

Have a good day folks!