# android studio .. how do i fix this?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Answer (score 0):

try from this links,

[Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)

[Android Studio: Unable to start the daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471311/android-studio-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process)

may be this is useful to you.